# Paint.net file recovery

Tags: paint.net

I was working on a project today on Paint.net when it suddenly crashed before I saved my work. Is there a way I can recover it?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, you can't: As of July 3, 2016, Paint.NET has no autosave or file recovery feature.

[People on the getpaint.net forums have been asking for this feature](http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/108929-another-please-give-us-an-autosave-thread/), [some as far back as 2007](http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/3135-feature-request-auto-save/)! ([index of misery](https://www.google.com/search?q=paint.net%20autosave%20site:forums.getpaint.net))

You'll need to either use another program, or make regular saves and backups in the future. :(